# While loop asks for input twice, instead of breaking first time

Tags: c

Esentially I need to constantly load in a character and a number until '-' is entered. But instead of breaking immediatly after entering '-', the loop asks for the input again, and then breaks.

```
while (c != '-') {
    scanf(" %c", &c);
    scanf("%d", &n);
}
```

Comment: it can't know what c is until the whole inner block is complete. You have to check for the value of c inside the block before checking for the second input.

Comment: Please try to explain the loop to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)... What is there to break the loop after you input the character for `c`?

Comment: if you input `"114-5<ENTER>"`, the first loop will have `c == '1'; n == 14;`, the 2nd loop will have `c == '-'; n == 5;` ... and the `<ENTER>` will still be waiting in the input buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing the character that was entered *before* the last number. You need to test the character first, and then ask for the number.

```
while (true) {
    scanf(" %c", &c);
    if (c == '-') {
        break;
    }
    scanf("%d", &n);
}
```